Updating One List from Another List in C#
I have a class like shown below :
        public class Student
        {
           public int studid {get; set;}
           public string Name {get; set;}
           public int Age {get; set;}
           public string Division {get; set;}
        }

And I am having 2 lists of Student class as shown below:
       // taken some records from DB 10 minutes before
       List<Student> tempData = new List<Student>();   
       

After sometimes, the datas are updated in the Database.
       // having updated datas in database
       List<Student> ActualData = DB.GetData(); 

I want to update tempData from ActualData based on studid's in the tempdata.
Because tempData values are binded to a DataGrid. So I want to update only the students in the tempData.
Suppose that the tempData has 3 records and ActualData has 10 records. So I want to replace only these 3 records in the tempData from ActualData (which is having same studid's in the tempData).
Can we do it without using for loop ? May be using LINQ? Thanks.

You can show respect for those who might help you by making the minimal effort to ensure your code snippets are well-formatted, and not indented way to the right.

What should happen if a student is no longer in DB? You got a student that is in tempData but not in ActualData?

Try this code: it is looping over tempData items, finding corresponding object in ActualData list and updating the item, based on found item:
foreach (var tempStudent in tempData)
{
    var actualStudent = ActualData.FirstOrDefault(x => x.studid == tempStudent.studid);

    // If student is not found, then do nothing.
    // Maybe you should remove it?
    if (actualStudent is null) continue;
    
    tempStudent.Age = actualStudent.Age;
    tempStudent.Name = actualStudent.Name;
    tempStudent.Division = actualStudent.Division;
}

